# Using portion of a field in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

How to use portion of a field for `awk` script?

The input file:

```
123456789,0,0,4,1,6,8,6
987654321,0,0,8,4,6,9,8
251335549,8,9,6,3,1,8,8
897465419,8,1,8,9,4,7,9
```

I need to select the *3rd* character of the `$1`, to apply it to a certain operation.

Example:

```
$9 = (3rd character from $1) - 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [awk string function `substr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13):

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '$9 = substr($1,3,1)' <file
```